# For loop with glob not working as desired in Python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, glob

I'm trying to have Python scan through my directory, then extract the text and convert each pdf into a dataframe. Below is my attempt, I suspect the error may be around the for loop/def function syntax but I cannot figure it out.

The code in the function is correct (although could be written more efficiently) and produces my desired dataframe when I input the file name directly into pdfplumber.open('filename.pdf'), but the goal is to have python put each pdf into the function in succession, producing x amount of dataframes as the end result.

```
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

directory = glob.glob('*.pdf')
def pdf_function():
    for f in directory:
        pdf = pdfplumber.open(f)
        page = pdf.pages[0]
        text = page.extract_text()
        pdf.close()
        text2 = text.splitlines()
        df = pd.DataFrame(text2, columns=['Location, Billed Amount'])
        df[['Location', 'Billed Amount']] = df['Location, Billed Amount'].str.split('Impressions', 1, expand=True)
        df = df.drop('Location, Billed Amount', 1)
        df.columns = ['Location','Billed Amount']
        df = df[~df['Billed Amount'].isnull()]
        df = df.replace(' ,', '', regex=True)
        df['Location'] = df['Location'].replace('LA Cluster', 'DTLA', regex=True)
        df['Location'] = df['Location'].replace('\d+', '', regex=True)
        df['Location'] = df['Location'].replace(' ,', '', regex=True)
        df['Location'] = df['Location'].str.strip()
    return
```

any help?

Comment: You're reassigning the same variables each time through the loop. So at the end of the loop you just have the results from the last file. Also, the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Where do you *call* the function?

Comment: If this should all be in a single dataframe, you need to create `df` before the loop, not each time through the loop.

Comment: @Barmar Creating the dataframe before the loop makes a lot more sense. So the loop will extract the text from each pdf in the directory and add it to the dataframe, and then once the loop is done, I apply all the cleaning/formatting to the dataframe?